# How discuss the matrix positive definition $A=B^TB$?

Tags: linear-algebra

let

> $$B=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1&1&\cdots&1\\
> a_{1}&a_{2}&\cdots&a_{m}\\
> a^2_{1}&a^2_{2}&\cdots&a^2_{m}\\
> \cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
> a^{n-1}_{1}&a^{n-1}_{2}&\cdots&a^{n-1}_{m}
> \end{bmatrix}$$

Discuss the matrix positive definition (meaning that,when $a_{i}$ such what conditions) $A = B ^ TB $ ？

My try: let 
$$|A|=|B^TB|=|B|^2?$$
and I can't.Thank you for you help.and I guess

> when $a_{i}\neq a_{j},\forall i\neq j$.then $A$ is  positive definition matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix $B$ has $m$ columns so its rank is at most $m$. When ${\sf rank}(B)=m$ we say that $B$ has full rank.

The answer to your question is YES. In fact, one has a much stronger result :

**Theorem 1**. The matrix $A=B^TB$ is positive definite
if and only if $B$ has full rank $m$.

**Proof** “if” Let $X$ be a vector in ${\mathbb R}^m$, one has $\langle AX,X\rangle=\langle B^TBX,X\rangle=\langle BX,BX\rangle=\|BX\|^2$ where $\|.\|$ is the usual euclidian norm. Also, if $\langle AX,X\rangle=0$, then $\|BX\|=0,BX=0$, hence
$X=0$ since $B$ has rank $\geq m$. So $A$ is positive definite.

“only if” : If $B$ has rank $< m$, there is a nonzero $X\in {\mathbb R}^m$ with
$BX=0$. Then $\langle AX,X\rangle=0$ and $X$ is nonzero, so $A$ cannot be positive definite.

Combine that with

**Theorem 2** Let $B$ be the [Van der Monde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) $(a_j^{i-1})_{1\leq i\leq n,1\leq j \leq n}$.Then $B$ has full rank $m$ iff the  $a_j$ are distinct.

**Proof** : see [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant).

Comment: Hello,@Ewan Delanoy, But the matrix $B$ is not $n\times n$,so we can't have $det|B|$

Comment: @chinamath this is not a problem, see my update

Comment: Your Theorem has something weird. $B$ is assumed invertible (hence square). The condition of full rank then would be automatic. (Also one doesn't say that a rank has full rank.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen corrected all this, thanks.